# Deploying a Tensorflow model, getting an error

Tags: android, tensorflow, neural-network

I am importing my trained Tensorflow model to android. I saved my input and output tensors, namely "input" and "y_", respectively.

This is my code in Android Studio:

```
 private static ActivityInference activityInferenceInstance;
    private TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface;
    private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/optimized_har.pb";
    private static final String INPUT_NODE = "input";
    private static final String[] OUTPUT_NODES = {"y_"};
    private static final String OUTPUT_NODE =  "y_";
    private static final long[] INPUT_SIZE = {1,1800};
    private static final int OUTPUT_SIZE = 6;
    private static AssetManager assetManager;
```

Then this function to return the probabilities at the output:

```
public float[] getActivityProb(float[] input_signal)
    {
        float[] result = new float[OUTPUT_SIZE];
        inferenceInterface.feed(INPUT_NODE,input_signal,INPUT_SIZE);
        inferenceInterface.run(OUTPUT_NODES);
        inferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_NODE,result);
        return result;
    }
```

But my app crashes. I am sure the input and output dimensions are correct (or maybe not). But I checked that they are the same (both declared sized in Android Studio and the actual sizes in Python).

What is the possible of this error? Is there a better way to debug in Android Studio?

Also, I found the line which causes the error:

```
inferenceInterface.run(OUTPUT_NODES);
```

Comment: firstly check the error what you get in log or debug that app?

Comment: There are no errors, but the app crashes in my phone. I will also edit the question. I find which line causes the error.   `inferenceInterface.run(OUTPUT_NODES);`

Comment: It is that line