# Deploying a tensorflow model in android getting inputsize mismatch error

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have been following the following tensorflow tutorial, training in python and deploying in android.

Training code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util import convert_variables_to_constants
# Just disables the warning, doesn't enable AVX/FMA
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
#matplotlib inline
plt.style.use('ggplot')


def read_data(file_path):
    column_names = ['user-id', 'activity', 'timestamp', 'x-axis', 'y-axis', 'z-axis']
    data = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, names=column_names)
    return data


def feature_normalize(dataset):
    mu = np.mean(dataset, axis=0)
    sigma = np.std(dataset, axis=0)
    return (dataset - mu) / sigma


def plot_axis(ax, x, y, title):
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax.set_ylim([min(y) - np.std(y), max(y) + np.std(y)])
    ax.set_xlim([min(x), max(x)])
    ax.grid(True)


def plot_activity(activity, data):
    fig, (ax0, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize=(15, 10), sharex=True)
    plot_axis(ax0, data['timestamp'], data['x-axis'], 'x-axis')
    plot_axis(ax1, data['timestamp'], data['y-axis'], 'y-axis')
    plot_axis(ax2, data['timestamp'], data['z-axis'], 'z-axis')
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.2)
    fig.suptitle(activity)
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.90)
    plt.show()


def windows(data, size):
    start = 0
    while start < data.count():
        yield int(start), int(start + size)
        start += (size / 2)


def segment_signal(data, window_size=90):
    segments = np.empty((0, window_size, 3))
    labels = np.empty((0))
    for (start, end) in windows(data['timestamp'], window_size):
        x = data["x-axis"][start:end]
        y = data["y-axis"][start:end]
        z = data["z-axis"][start:end]
        if (len(dataset['timestamp'][start:end]) == window_size):
            segments = np.vstack([segments, np.dstack([x, y, z])])
            labels = np.append(labels, stats.mode(data["activity"][start:end])[0][0])
    return segments, labels


def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.0, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def depthwise_conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(x, W, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')


def apply_depthwise_conv(x, kernel_size, num_channels, depth):
    weights = weight_variable([1, kernel_size, num_channels, depth])
    biases = bias_variable([depth * num_channels])
    return tf.nn.relu(tf.add(depthwise_conv2d(x, weights), biases))


def apply_max_pool(x, kernel_size, stride_size):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 1, kernel_size, 1],
                          strides=[1, 1, stride_size, 1], padding='VALID')


dataset = read_data('WISDM_ar_v1.1_raw_copy.txt')

dataset.dropna(axis=0, how='any', inplace= True)
dataset.drop_duplicates(['user-id','activity','timestamp', 'x-axis', 'y-axis', 'z-axis'], keep= 'first', inplace= True)

dataset['x-axis'] = feature_normalize(dataset['x-axis'])
dataset['y-axis'] = feature_normalize(dataset['y-axis'])
dataset['z-axis'] = feature_normalize(dataset['z-axis'])


# for activity in np.unique(dataset["activity"]):
#     subset = dataset[dataset["activity"] == activity][:180]
#     plot_activity(activity,subset)

segments, labels = segment_signal(dataset)
labels = np.asarray(pd.get_dummies(labels), dtype=np.int8)
reshaped_segments = segments.reshape(len(segments), 1, 90, 3)

train_test_split = np.random.rand(len(reshaped_segments)) < 0.70
train_x = reshaped_segments[train_test_split]
train_y = labels[train_test_split]
test_x = reshaped_segments[~train_test_split]
test_y = labels[~train_test_split]

input_height = 1 # 1-Dimensional convulotion
input_width = 90 #window
num_labels = 6 #output labels
num_channels = 3 #input columns

batch_size = 10
kernel_size = 60
depth = 60
num_hidden = 1000

learning_rate = 0.0001
training_epochs = 1#8

total_batches = train_x.shape[0] # batch_size

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,input_height,input_width,num_channels])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,num_labels])

c = apply_depthwise_conv(X,kernel_size,num_channels,depth)
p = apply_max_pool(c,20,2)
c = apply_depthwise_conv(p,6,depth*num_channels,depth//10)

shape = c.get_shape().as_list()
c_flat = tf.reshape(c, [-1, shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])

f_weights_l1 = weight_variable([shape[1] * shape[2] * depth * num_channels * (depth//10), num_hidden])
f_biases_l1 = bias_variable([num_hidden])
f = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(c_flat, f_weights_l1),f_biases_l1))

out_weights = weight_variable([num_hidden, num_labels])
out_biases = bias_variable([num_labels])
y_ = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(f, out_weights) + out_biases,name="y_")

loss = -tf.reduce_sum(Y * tf.log(y_))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(loss)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_,1), tf.argmax(Y,1)) #difference between correct output and expected output
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

cost_history = np.empty(shape=[1], dtype=float)


with tf.Session() as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        for b in range(total_batches):
            offset = (b * batch_size) % (train_y.shape[0] - batch_size)
            batch_x = train_x[offset:(offset + batch_size), :, :, :]
            batch_y = train_y[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
            _, c = session.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
            cost_history = np.append(cost_history, c)
        print "Epoch: ", epoch, " Training Loss: ", c, " Training Accuracy: ",
        session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: train_x, Y: train_y})
    print "Testing Accuracy:", session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: test_x, Y: test_y})

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    tf.train.write_graph(session.graph_def, '.', './model/har.pbtxt')
    saver.save(session, save_path="./model/har.ckpt")

    # File_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graph', session.graph)
```

Freezing the model:

```
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph
from tensorflow.python.tools import optimize_for_inference_lib
import tensorflow as tf

freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph = "./model/har.pbtxt",  input_saver = "",
             input_binary = False, input_checkpoint = "./model/har.ckpt", output_node_names = "y_",
             restore_op_name = "save/restore_all", filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0",
             output_graph = "./model/frozen_har.pb", clear_devices = True, initializer_nodes = "")

input_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
with tf.gfile.Open("./model/frozen_har.pb", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    input_graph_def.ParseFromString(data)

output_graph_def = optimize_for_inference_lib.optimize_for_inference(
        input_graph_def,
        ["input"],
        ["y_"],
        tf.float32.as_datatype_enum)

f = tf.gfile.FastGFile("./model/optimized_har.pb", "w")
f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Error that I get when I try to freeze the model:

```
2018-04-05 10:00:50.604122: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
Converted 8 variables to const ops.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aawesh/PycharmProjects/Human-Activity-Recognition-using-CNN/Freeze.py", line 19, in <module>
    tf.float32.as_datatype_enum)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference_lib.py", line 109, in optimize_for_inference
    placeholder_type_enum)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/strip_unused_lib.py", line 83, in strip_unused
    raise KeyError("The following input nodes were not found: %s\n" % not_found)
KeyError: "The following input nodes were not found: set(['input'])\n"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Android part:

MainActivity.java

```
package io.github.aqibsaeed.activityrecognition;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private final int N_SAMPLES = 90;
    private static List<Float> x;
    private static List<Float> y;
    private static List<Float> z;
    private static List<Float> input_signal;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private ActivityInference activityInference;

    private TextView downstairsTextView;
    private TextView joggingTextView;
    private TextView sittingTextView;
    private TextView standingTextView;
    private TextView upstairsTextView;
    private TextView walkingTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        x = new ArrayList<Float>();
        y = new ArrayList<Float>();
        z = new ArrayList<Float>();
        input_signal = new ArrayList<Float>();

        downstairsTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.downstairs_prob);
        joggingTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.jogging_prob);
        sittingTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sitting_prob);
        standingTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.standing_prob);
        upstairsTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.upstairs_prob);
        walkingTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.walking_prob);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        activityInference = new ActivityInference(getApplicationContext());
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        activityPrediction();
        x.add(event.values[0]);
        y.add(event.values[1]);
        z.add(event.values[2]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }

    private void activityPrediction()
    {
        if(x.size() == N_SAMPLES && y.size() == N_SAMPLES && z.size() == N_SAMPLES) {
            // Mean normalize the signal
            normalize();

            // Copy all x,y and z values to one array of shape N_SAMPLES*3
            input_signal.addAll(x); input_signal.addAll(y); input_signal.addAll(z);

            // Perform inference using Tensorflow
            float[] results = activityInference.getActivityProb(toFloatArray(input_signal));

            downstairsTextView.setText(Float.toString(round(results[0],2)));
            joggingTextView.setText(Float.toString(round(results[1],2)));
            sittingTextView.setText(Float.toString(round(results[2],2)));
            standingTextView.setText(Float.toString(round(results[3],2)));
            upstairsTextView.setText(Float.toString(round(results[4],2)));
            walkingTextView.setText(Float.toString(round(results[5],2)));

            // Clear all the values
            x.clear(); y.clear(); z.clear(); input_signal.clear();
        }
    }

    private float[] toFloatArray(List<Float> list)
    {
        int i = 0;
        float[] array = new float[list.size()];

        for (Float f : list) {
            array[i++] = (f != null ? f : Float.NaN);
        }
        return array;
    }

    private void normalize()
    {
        float x_m = 0.662868f; float y_m = 7.255639f; float z_m = 0.411062f;
        float x_s = 6.849058f; float y_s = 6.746204f; float z_s = 4.754109f;

        for(int i = 0; i < N_SAMPLES; i++){
            x.set(i,((x.get(i) - x_m)/x_s));
            y.set(i,((y.get(i) - y_m)/y_s));
            z.set(i,((z.get(i) - z_m)/z_s));
        }
    }

    public static float round(float d, int decimalPlace) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(d));
        bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        return bd.floatValue();
    }
}
```

ActivityInference.java

```
package io.github.aqibsaeed.activityrecognition;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;

import org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface;


public class ActivityInference {
//    static {
//        System.loadLibrary("tensorflow_inference");
//    }

    private static ActivityInference activityInferenceInstance;
    private TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface;
//    private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/optimized_har.pb";
    private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/optimized_har_1.pb";
    private static final String INPUT_NODE = "input";
    private static final String[] OUTPUT_NODES = {"y_"};
    private static final String OUTPUT_NODE = "y_";
    private static final long[] INPUT_SIZE = {1,270};
    private static final int OUTPUT_SIZE = 6;
    private static AssetManager assetManager;

    public static ActivityInference getInstance(final Context context)
    {
        if (activityInferenceInstance == null)
        {
            activityInferenceInstance = new ActivityInference(context);
        }
        return activityInferenceInstance;
    }

    public ActivityInference(final Context context) {
        this.assetManager = context.getAssets();
        inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(assetManager, MODEL_FILE);
    }

    public float[] getActivityProb(float[] input_signal)
    {
        float[] result = new float[OUTPUT_SIZE];
        inferenceInterface.feed(INPUT_NODE,input_signal,INPUT_SIZE);
        inferenceInterface.run(OUTPUT_NODES);
        inferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_NODE,result);
        //Downstairs    Jogging   Sitting   Standing    Upstairs    Walking
        return result;
    }
}
```

[Implementation of CNN for Human Activity Recognition](http://aqibsaeed.github.io/2016-11-04-human-activity-recognition-cnn/)

[Deploying the trained model in android](http://aqibsaeed.github.io/2017-05-02-deploying-tensorflow-model-andorid-device-human-activity-recognition/)

My questions are:

1. While deploying, it is using the node named 'input'. But we do not have such tensor name while training. This is causing problem while freezing the graph. How can I resolve that?
2. While training the model, it is using the input tensor of shape 4 dimension. But, in android we are feeding only a list. How is it working?

Please help me. I have been stucked on this for a long time.

[Similar question has been asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48166439/deploying-a-tensorflow-model-getting-an-error)
But it is not the duplicate. I did not find his answer there as well.

My try: I somehow managed to free a model and run it on android. I got following error. I still need help to freeze a model:

```
04-05 10:16:43.988 13148-13148/tictactoe.com.tictacoe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: tictactoe.com.tictacoe, PID: 13148
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input must be 4-dimensional[1,270]
                                                                             [[Node: depthwise = DepthwiseConv2dNative[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_input_0_0, Variable)]]
                                                                            at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)
                                                                            at org.tensorflow.Session.access$100(Session.java:48)
                                                                            at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runHelper(Session.java:298)
                                                                            at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.run(Session.java:248)
                                                                            at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:230)
                                                                            at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:197)
                                                                            at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:187)
                                                                            at io.github.aqibsaeed.activityrecognition.ActivityInference.getActivityProb(ActivityInference.java:43)
                                                                            at io.github.aqibsaeed.activityrecognition.MainActivity.activityPrediction(MainActivity.java:89)
                                                                            at io.github.aqibsaeed.activityrecognition.MainActivity.onSensorChanged(MainActivity.java:68)
                                                                            at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:503)
                                                                            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6895)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Post log in text with code indent mode(Ctrl+K) not image

Comment: Okay I will edit the post with code. The image of logcat is what I tried. You may disregard that image.

Comment: @Prateek I have updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: You're passing "input" to `optimize_for_inference`, which as you say isn't in your graph. It sounds like you just need to change that to the list of nodes you want to feed during inference. Do you know which nodes you want to feed?

Comment: I want to feed the main input node and output node is "y_". By main input nide I mean, the point where raw data will be feeded